# need jquery .load suggestions?

Tags: jquery, load

Im loading both a menu and a page content with the .load.
First the menu should load and when click on one menu item it should load the url and that "content" in the "container".

This works but something is wrong, because it messes up the loadFacebook function below so I need to change it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadPage();

});
function loadPage(url) {

    $('#guiden_menyn').load('manmade/guiden/guiden_menyn.html #content',
            hijackLinks);

    $('#container').load(url + ' #content', hijackLinks);

}
function hijackLinks() {
    $('#guiden_menyn a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        loadPage(e.target.href);

    });

}
```

And a link i the menu "guiden_menyn.html"  looks like this:

```
<a  class="lank" href="manmade/guiden/tipsa.html">

function loadFacebook() {

    $('#container').load(
            'http://www.manmade.se/manmade/guiden/facebook_onweb.html',
            function() {
                FB.XFBML.parse();
            });
}
```

Maybe I need to set a onclick to run the function on the link instead of the   "$('#guiden_menyn a')...."?

How should it be, any suggestions appreciated, thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by 'it messes up'? what is the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: On the loadFacebook function I use a onclick to run it, and I guess that it then runs 2 times, since the  $('#guiden_menyn a') is looking for every a in the menu. So when I run the loadFacebook it doesnt display the page, its just a white page.

Comment: i don't see any call to `loadFacebook()` in your code, please provide more code snippets.

Comment: I use this <a class="lank" href="#" onclick="loadFacebook();">

Comment: If I remove this loadPage(e.target.href);, then the loadFacebook work every time, but then of course the pages are not opened in the "container" div.

Comment: you're being unclear, where did `<a  class="lank" href="manmade/guiden/tipsa.html">` come from? why is it in the question body? please update your question for clarity.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9844/discussion-between-eliran-malka-and-claes-gustavsson)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a function like this
Here is html

```
<a  class="lank" href="manmade/guiden/tipsa.html">
```

Give lank class to every hyperlink
Then

```
$('.lank').click(function(){
      var link = $(this).attr('href');
      loadPage(link );
});
```

Comment: In latest jQuery it changed  attr -> prop